# Application closing before shutdown c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service, shutdown

I have created a console application that runs through a windows service.

Service starts the application and runs it well.

The problem is when i attempt to restart/shutdown my PC, application is closing before the actual shutdown.

So what happens is the service restarts the application again before shutdown.

Even I tried without service. Application is closing before shutdown.

How can I tell my service to know that pc is going to shutdown/restart. So dont restart the application.

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Err... you want your app to be open after shutdown?

Comment: Do you expect it to linger on and close *after* shutdown?  What you see is the usual and sensible behavior for an app.

Comment: No, I want my service to know that pc is going to shutdown/restart. So dont restart the application.

Comment: @user1465461 Are you trying to write a program that will prevent the user from shutting down the computer?

Comment: You can set an event using Task Scheduler, I think there's "just before shutdown" trigger there. Not sure about services, though, they should be normally closed.

Comment: Thanks, but i want to do this in Services

Comment: Soddin' console apps.  With a GUI, it would have been easy to catch the shutdown/close message and signal the service to terminate before the GUI.

Answer (score 3):

Your service can register for notification with `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx` and will receive the `SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN` notification when the shutdown process begins. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685149(v=vs.85).aspx for more information.

Comment: So will i be able to shutdown the service before the PC shutdown

Comment: That is not what Jonathan is suggesting.  Your app and service will still be closed during the PC shutdown, but by registering for `SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN`, the OS will notify your service before the actual shutdown begins, so your service can choose to ignore the app's subsequent shutdown and not restart it.